# mysql query to retrive data from two tables having a common field

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have two tables named `customer` and `order`. They have a common field which is `o_id`. How do I retrieve the data from both the tables together in a `datagridview`?

Example:

> table -customers

```
 o_id   |     c_id     |  name    | address  | tel_no
```

> table- orders

```
 o_id   |  starter   | rice     | gravy    | dessert
```

I want the details to be retrieved as follows

```
o_id   |c_id       | name     | address   | tel_no   |  starter  | rice | gravy | dessert
```

What type of `JOIN` should I use and how?

I tried using the below query

```
SELECT * FROM cms.order inner join cms.menu on cms.order.o_id=cms.menu.o_id
```

But the problem with the above code is that the `o_id` column is displayed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT c.o_id, c.c_id, c.name, c.address,
    c.tel_no, o.starter, o.rice, o.gravy. o.desserts
FROM order o INNER JOIN customers c 
ON  o.o_id=c.o_id
```

**Output**

```
o_id   |c_id       | name     | address   | tel_no   |  starter  | rice | gravy | dessert
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply don't want the columns to display twice, then instead of `SELECT *` you need to specify which columns you want to `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the columns that you want to retrieve

```
 SELECT o.o_id, o.c_id, o.name, o.address,
        o.tel_no, m.starter, m.rice, m.gravy. m.desserts
 FROM order o inner join menu m on o.o_id=m.o_id
```

By the way, you talk about a customer/order tables but then you use a order/menutable.
This is confusing. However, I hope that the answer is clear enough to highlight the problem